# How exactly kernel, udev and DBus mount external devices?

Tags: kernel, automount, udev, udisks

I'm trying to understand how exactly SDcard unmounting/ejecting works in Ubuntu to debug context of this issue:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1980080

Looked [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979803/attaching-an-external-device-udev-hal-dbus-and-mini-ubuntu) getting essential info:

```
kernel/linux → sysfs → udev → udisks2 → GVolumeMonitor → desktop-manager (usually, same as the file manager).
udisks2 is the first daemon to provide an API through DBUS
```

Now my concern is what actually should happen on correctly working system when eject button is hit via Gnome or `eject /dev/mmcblk0` command launched from command line. In my case `eject` command fails with error code `1` whether `/dev/mmcblk0p1` partition is mounted or not. The `strace eject /dev/mmcblk0` includes then the following lines:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/mmcblk0", O_RDWR|O_EXCL|O_NONBLOCK) = 3
ioctl(3, CDROM_LOCKDOOR, 0)             = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
ioctl(3, SG_GET_VERSION_NUM, 0x7ffd53f9b2e8) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
ioctl(3, FDEJECT, 0x55874d4359d0)       = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
ioctl(3, MTIOCTOP, 0x7ffd53f9b320)      = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
write(2, "eject: ", 7eject: )                  = 7
write(2, "unable to eject", 15unable to eject)         = 15
```

wondering if this mean that the exit code will be 0 only for devices which can by physically and programatically ejected like CDROM drive. And how other userspace programs like different Gnome services interpret this output.

`udevadm monitor` shows the following lines:

### Card inserted

```
KERNEL[49421.254375] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:72:00.0/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa (mmc)
KERNEL[49421.255242] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/179:0 (bdi)
UDEV  [49421.256281] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:72:00.0/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa (mmc)
UDEV  [49421.256354] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/179:0 (bdi)
KERNEL[49421.264022] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:72:00.0/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa/block/mmcblk0 (block)
KERNEL[49421.264062] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:72:00.0/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p1 (block)
KERNEL[49421.264093] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:72:00.0/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa (mmc)
UDEV  [49421.321281] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:72:00.0/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa/block/mmcblk0 (block)
UDEV  [49421.409280] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:72:00.0/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p1 (block)
UDEV  [49421.413271] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:72:00.0/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa (mmc)
```

### Eject button hit in Gnome:

```
KERNEL[49428.212348] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:72:00.0/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p1 (block)
KERNEL[49428.213105] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:72:00.0/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa/block/mmcblk0 (block)
KERNEL[49428.213189] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:72:00.0/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p1 (block)
UDEV  [49428.215677] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:72:00.0/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p1 (block)
UDEV  [49428.242018] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:72:00.0/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa/block/mmcblk0 (block)
UDEV  [49428.310305] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:72:00.0/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p1 (block)
```

In above I'm mostly concerned about the reason of readding device by kernel in 3rd line.

### Card physically removed:

```
KERNEL[49432.237855] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:72:00.0/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p1 (block)
KERNEL[49432.238271] remove   /devices/virtual/bdi/179:0 (bdi)
KERNEL[49432.238678] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:72:00.0/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa/block/mmcblk0 (block)
UDEV  [49432.241920] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:72:00.0/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p1 (block)
UDEV  [49432.242568] remove   /devices/virtual/bdi/179:0 (bdi)
UDEV  [49432.245293] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:72:00.0/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa/block/mmcblk0 (block)
KERNEL[49432.269966] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:72:00.0/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa (mmc)
KERNEL[49432.270065] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:72:00.0/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa (mmc)
UDEV  [49432.271890] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:72:00.0/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa (mmc)
UDEV  [49432.273292] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:72:00.0/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa (mmc)
```