# How to disable on lubuntu 22.04 the opening of the browse window when a USB device is automounted?

Tags: usb, lubuntu, filemanager, automount

I'm working with lubuntu 22.04. When I insert an USB device into one of the USB port of the system the device is automatically mounted and a files browse window is open on the screen.

**I need to maintain the automount** of the device but I need to stop the opening of the files browse window.

I have tried to use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false
```

My intentions were to disable the automount and after that to define a new script (based on [this link](https://andreafortuna.org/2019/06/26/automount-usb-devices-on-linux-using-udev-and-systemd/)) that mounts the USB device without open the browse window, but the previous command disables the automount of all devices (keyboard, mouse and so on).

I have searched a lot and read many post (for example [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89244/how-to-disable-automount-in-nautiluss-preferences) and [this other](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979803/attaching-an-external-device-udev-hal-dbus-and-mini-ubuntu) about the same topic), but none give me a satisfactory answer.

So how can I disable the opening of the browse window when a USB device is automounted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had gnome instead of lubuntu this would work. You have to make it in filemanager.

```
pcmanfm-qt --show-pref general
```

Sorry for german text in image.

[image: filemanager]

Where my mouse corser is it have to be untickt.

Comment: Thank you very much (yesterday I didn't understand the suggestion because the german language)

Comment: No problem i haven't figured out how to  show in English.

Answer (score 2):

It's the third option to uncheck to achieve what you like. Check also the option of the "mount" widget in the panel. All of "volume" is also about USB.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much